# Why this simple C++ program is giving unexpected result?

Tags: c++

I made a simple C++ program. I expect a floating point output of 5/9, but is is zero. Can someone comment, why output is unexpected i.e. zero?

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;
void fun(double *ptr);

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double a;
    fun(&a);
    cout<<a<<endl; // why not floating point 5/9??
}

void fun (double *ptr)
{
    *ptr=(5/9);
}
```

Comment: Next time make sure you search a bit before asking.

Comment: The topic to search is *integer division*.

Answer (score 7):

`5/9` will result in `0` because it is `int` division.

You would need to do

```
void fun (double *ptr)
{
    *ptr = (5.0 / 9.0);
}
```

You need to use the correct type literals:

```
5      // int
5.0    // double
5.0f   // float
5u     // unsigned int
5l     // long
5ul    // unsigned long
```

Comment: but 5/9 shouldn't be stored in double data type variable?

Comment: No. `5` is of type `int`, and so is `9`. You would have to either cast each literal to `double` (or at least one so the other is promoted), or use `5.0` which is a `double` literal.

Comment: @user3705273, `5` is `int`, `9` is `int`, thus `5/9` is `int`.

Comment: so `(5.0/9.0)` does is become `float ` or `double`? confused here.

Comment: It will become a `double`. `5.0` is a literal `double`. The `float` equivalent is `5.0f`. See my most recent edit.